# Show that $\sum_{j=1}^k a^2_j\geq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, inner-products, least-squares

Suppose $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ are $k$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ satisfying for any $1 \leq i, j \leq k$,
$\langle x_i, x_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$. For each $1 \leq j \leq k$, let $a_j$ be the 1st component of $x_j$ . Show that
$\sum_{j=1}^k a^2_j\geq 1$. I am kind of getting a feel that I have to use least square method but unable to figure it out. Please help.

Edit:
The above inequality will be reversed as Kavi Rama Murty observed. I actually made a typo but don't want to change the question drastically as suggested by the math people. So I am adding this that we have to prove $\sum_{j=1}^k a^2_j\geq 1$.

Comment: Is something missing? Take $n=3$, $k=2$, $x_1=j$, $x_2=k$, so $ a_1=a_2=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Take $n=3, x_1=(0,1,0), x_2=(0,0,1)$.

EDIT: The reverse inequality follows by Parseval's identity Extend $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$ to an orthonomal basis $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and conclude that $1=\|e_1\|^{2}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} |\langle e_1, x_i \rangle|^{2} \geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} |\langle e_1, x_i \rangle|^{2}$ where $e_1=(1,0,0,,,0)$.

Comment: My bad, I wrote it wrong. The inequality will be reversed.

Comment: @Ri-Li Since your earlier question has already received a valid answer, I would suggest to not disturb the original question and add your edit in a separate section at the end of your post.

Comment: I have done that. Thanks for the suggestion